# VBA code to remove a set of words from column E and highlight the same set of words in column D

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am relatively new to Excel and VBA , i have been writing a code where i want to remove a set of words from column E and i need to highlight the same set of words in column D ;

The columns before running the macro

### Column D

red color
blue sky
green rocket

### Column E

red color
blue sky
green rocket

After columns running the macro with the set of words ( red , blue , green )

### Column D

**red** color
 
**blue** sky 
**green** Rocket

### Column E

color 
sky 
Rocket

I have recorded the macro and been using the find and replace statements . The problem with this is the number of rows i have are around 20,000 to 30,000 . So i need the macro to work efficiently and as quickly as possible . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are working with a large number of rows, I would first reccommend that you write your own macro rather than attempting to record one. I would start by writing a subroutine with a basic For Loop that accesses each of the rows in the columns you are interested in.

```
Dim i as long
Dim j as long
Dim finalRowEColumn as long
Dim finalRowDColumn as long
Dim eCellValue as string

finalRow = <Insert your final row here, or dynamically get it from your range of rows>
For i = 1 to finalRowEColumn
    eCellValue = Range("E" & i).Value
    For j = 1 to finalRowDColumn
        dCellValue = Range("D" & j).Value
        'This inner loop will allow you do perform comparisons with the values in each of the columns
        'You may set cell formats, values, etc. Depending on your parameters eCellValue and dCellValue.
    Next j
Next i
```

I hope this is a good start.